# Drupal 7 Custom db_query from External Script?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-nodes

I'm using external script to make Node `Insert`/ `Edit`/ `Delete` by calling proper Drupal headers and bootstrap. I included the calls like following (in the script under Drupal Root Directory):

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');
require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'biblio') . '/includes/biblio.contributors.inc';
```

Actually it is working fine for `Node Actions (node_load, node_save)` and `SELECT db_query` but **exactly NO** for `DELETE Queries`.

I mean, `node_load()` `node_save()` `db_query("SELECT ..."` is already working..

but totally **NOT WORKING** with:

```
db_query("DELETE FROM {biblio} WHERE nid = %d", $nid);
```

.. even i used following way:

```
$deleted = db_delete('biblio')
          ->condition('nid', $nid)
          ->execute();
```

Not working again. And, EVEN I CAN'T use DIRECT PURE PHP MYSQL Query, like:

```
$mysql_connection = mysql_connect(MYSERVER, USERNAME, PASSW);
mysql_select_db(MYDATABASE, $mysql_connection);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM biblio WHERE nid=`".$nid."`");
```

My god! What is wrong?
Actually i'm trying to work around with BIBLIO Module and its Items by using external script.

What should i do now please?

My additional question is, Can't we use these queries for the Items in other Tables directly, rather then `node` Table. Coz as much as i noticed now, `node_delete` is also using for the items inside `node` table only. Can't we use that `node_delete` for other tables, like `biblio` table?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `db_query()` or `db_delete()` doesn't work because Drupal cannot load the necessary include files containing the database API functions or classes without knowing which database engine is begin used. That information is normally read from the [settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!default!default.settings.php/7) file used to run Drupal. When calling the database API from an external script, you need to provide that information.

Notice that `db_query("DELETE FROM {biblio} WHERE nid = %d", $nid);` is Drupal 6 code; for Drupal 7, you should use `db_delete()`.

Comment: D7 and I definitely used `db_delete()` as i've already mentioned in my question above.